# Adding element if attribute value does not exist

Tags: xml, xslt, string-matching

I am working with a file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item sort="gruun">
   <entrycl>
      <entry>gruun</entry>
      <gramt>bn</gramt></entrycl>
<translcl>
   <transl>green</transl>
</translcl>
</item>

<item>
   <entrycl placeatentry="gruun">
   <entryx>it is grün</entryx>
</entrycl>
   <translcl><transl>bla bla bla</transl>
</translcl>
</item>

<item>
   <entrycl placeatentry="blue">
   <entryx>it is blue</entryx></entrycl>
   <translcl>
      <transl>blu blu blu</transl>
</translcl>
</item>
</items>
```

I want to add an entrycl/entry with the value of @placeatentry, but only if there is no other item with this value. In order to facilitate checking the result I want to put an attribute (new ="yes").

The expected outcome is this:

```
<items>
<item sort="gruun">
   <entrycl>
      <entry>gruun</entry>
      <gramt>bn</gramt></entrycl>
<translcl>
   <transl>ble ble ble</transl>
<rem>existing item</rem>
</translcl>
</item>

<item>
   <entrycl placeatentry="gruun">
   <entryx>it is grün</entryx>
</entrycl>
   <translcl><transl>bla bla bla</transl>
</translcl>
</item>

<item>
   <entrycl new="yes">
      <entry>blue</entry>
   <entryx>it is blue</entryx></entrycl>
   <translcl>
      <transl>blu blu blu</transl>
</translcl>
</item>
</items>
```

Only the *blue* should a new entrycl/entry because there is no existing entrycl/entry with the value 'blue'.

The next step is to connect the items which did not get a new entrycl to the existing item, but I think how to do that.

I tried numerous times, benefitting from answers to other questions. Now I have this xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[entrycl/@placeatentry and not(//entry[.=entrycl/@placeatentry])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <entrycl>
        <entry new="yes">
          <xsl:value-of select="entrycl/@placeatentry"/>
        </entry>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entrycl/node()"/>
      </entrycl>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::entrycl)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  <!-- </xsl:if> -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yet my stylesheet places a new entry to all items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item sort="gruun">
      <entrycl>
         <entry>gruun</entry>
         <gramt>bn</gramt>
      </entrycl>
      <translcl>
         <transl>green</transl>
      </translcl>
   </item>
   <item>
      <entrycl>
         <entry new="yes">gruun</entry>
         <entryx>it is grün</entryx>
      </entrycl>
      <translcl>
         <transl>bla bla bla</transl>
      </translcl>
   </item>
   <item>
      <entrycl>
         <entry new="yes">blue</entry>
         <entryx>it is blue</entryx>
      </entrycl>
      <translcl>
         <transl>blu blu blu</transl>
      </translcl>
   </item>
</items>
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I overlooking something? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. It sounds like you should to define a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) in order to determine if a matching value exists.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k for your response. I am sorry if my question is not clear. I want to check for each `item/@placeatentry` if there is another item which has that value of `@placeatentry` in `entrycl/entry`. If so, do not change anything. If there is no such item then add to the current item a cluster `entrycl/entry` with the value of `@placeatentry`. e.g. `<entrycl><entry>blue</entry></entrycl>`. I actually tried the key option in different variants, yet I could not make it work, due to lack of experience and knowledge. I can adapt my examples if this can make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this **simplified** example can get you on the right track:

**XML**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <entrycl>
            <entry>gruun</entry>
        </entrycl>
    </item>
    <item>
        <entrycl placeatentry="gruun">
        </entrycl>
    </item>
    <item>
        <entrycl placeatentry="blue">
        </entrycl>
    </item>
</items>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="entrycl" use="entry" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entrycl[@placeatentry][not(key('k1', @placeatentry))]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="new">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <entrycl>
         <entry>gruun</entry>
      </entrycl>
   </item>
   <item>
      <entrycl placeatentry="gruun"/>
   </item>
   <item>
      <entrycl new="yes" placeatentry="blue"/>
   </item>
</items>
```

Note that the search for a matching value in `entry` includes the current `entrycl`.

Comment: It works, it places an attribute new=yes, but that is enough for now. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, good. FWIW, I think your attempt might have worked too (albeit less efficiently) if you had used the [current() function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#function-current) within your predicate.

Comment: On second thought, it would not - because you cannot use `current()` in a match pattern.